# Conways Game of Life - Glider pattern not working after the 1st mutation?

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on Conways Game of Life in Java and I've run into a bit of a problem.

My test case is the Glider Pattern but when I try to run the program, the glider only mutates correctly the first time in the second generation. Each subsequent generation after the first mutation is incorrect, and I can't figure out why.

[Glider Should Mutate like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8RDj.png)

[This is what I get from running the code, the Glider shouldn't be stuck with a repeating pattern.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtAUW.png)

World.class (Where the bulk of my methods reside)

```
public class World extends Patterns
{

    private char [][] world;
    private char [][] tempWorld;
    private int numRows;
    private int numCols;

//World Constructor
    public World (int r, int c)
    {
        this.numRows = r;
        this.numCols = c;
        world = new char [r][c];
        tempWorld = new char [r][c];
        initalizeWorld();

    }

//Initializes the world and fills array with blank spaces
    private void initalizeWorld()
    {
        // Initialize all indexes to ' '
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
            {
                world[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }   
    }   


//Creates and stores data in a temp world for the next Generation
    public void nextGen()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
            {
                changeCell(i,j);
            }
        }   
        world = tempWorld;      
    }

    //Prints world with *'s as Cells and O's as dead cells
    public void printWorld() 

    {
        // Print every value inside array 
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
            {
                if(world[i][j] == '*')
                    System.out.print(" ");

                System.out.print(world[i][j]);

                if(world[i][j] != '*')
                {
                    System.out.print("O");
                }

            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    //Method check's for neighbors of a cell
    public int getNeighbors(int x, int y)
    {
        int numNeighbors = 0;

        for(int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++)
            {

                if( (i >= 0) && (i < numRows) && (j < numCols) && (j >= 0))
                {                

                    if (world[i][j] == '*') 
                    {
                        numNeighbors++;
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        //don't count the cell itself
        return numNeighbors-1;

    }

    //Method uses getNeighbors to check whole array for every cells # of Neighbors
    public void checkAllNeighbors()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < numCols; j++) 
            {

                //if(world[i][j] == '*') 
                {
                    int neighbors = getNeighbors(i, j);
                    System.out.println("The cell at (" + i + ", " + j + ") has " + neighbors + " neighbors");
                }

            }
        }


    }

    //Method changes cell based on Neighbor Counts
    public void changeCell (int r, int c)
    {
        int count = getNeighbors(r,c);

        if (count == 3)
        {
            tempWorld [r][c] = '*';
        }
        else if (count >= 2 && count <= 3)
        {
            tempWorld [r][c] = '*'; 
        }
        else 
        {
            tempWorld [r][c] = ' ';
        }

    }

    //Gets world 
    public char [][] getWorld()
    {
        return world;
    }

    public void putGlider(int r, int c) 
    {
        char pattern[][] = getGlider();


        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pattern[0].length; j++)
            { 

                if ( (i + r < numRows) && (j + c < numCols) )
                {
                    world[i + r][j + c] = pattern[i][j];

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Patterns.class (Currently hold the Glider Pattern, but will house more later)

```
public class Patterns 
{
    private char[][] gliderArray = {{' ','*',' '},
                                   {' ',' ','*'},
                                   {'*','*','*'}};

    //private char [][] 

    public char[][] getGlider()
    {
        return gliderArray;
    }

}
```

test.class (Where I'm testing my methods)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        World test = new World (5,5);

        test.getWorld();
        test.putGlider(0,0);
        test.printWorld();

        System.out.println("Press enter to start generations!");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            test.nextGen();
            System.out.println(" ");
            test.printWorld();
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

    }

}
```

I've been working on this project for a while and I'm really stuck at this point. I have no idea what is wrong and how to fix it and I'm starting to go a little mad. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

New nextGen method based on Sci Prog suggestions, I'm not sure if I'm implementing the loop in the loop correctly.

```
public void nextGen()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
        {
            changeCell(i,j);
        }
    }   

    for (int r=0; r < this.numRows; r++)
          for (int c=0; c < this.numCols; c ++)
            world[r][c] = tempWorld[r][c];
}
```

I also changed my changeCell method but the new outputs are more off then what I had before.

Comment: When you say each mutation after the 1st is "incorrect" could you elaborate more on the exact reason that it is not correct?

Comment: In `getNeighbors` method, `(i < numRows) && (j < numCols)` shouldn't it be `i<numCols` and `j<numRows` ? Or your x and y variables are mislabled, as x is usually horizontal axis, that is column-based.

Comment: To "Even Bechtol" I've added some pictures to the top about what I meant about the mutations being incorrect

Answer (score 1):

First problem

The line `world = tempWorld;` copies the **reference** of the `tempWorld` array to the `world`.  Therefore, both variables refer to the same object in memory: after the first iteration, whenever you change an element in `tempWorld`, it also changes the same element in `world`.

You should manually copy each element, even if it is a longer code

```
for (int r=0; r < this.numRows; r++)
  for (int c=0; c < this.numCols; c ++)
    world[r][c] = tempWorld[r][c];
```

Second problem

in your `changeCell` method, you do not check if the current cell is ' ' or '*'.  (live cell=2 or 3, dead cell=3)

```
 //Method changes cell based on Neighbor Counts
public void changeCell (int r, int c)
{
    int count = getNeighbors(r,c);
    const char current = world[r][c];

    if ((current == ' ') && (count == 3))
    {
        tempWorld [r][c] = '*';
    }
    else if ((current=='*') && (count >= 2) && (count <= 3))
    {
        tempWorld [r][c] = '*'; 
    }
    else 
    {
        tempWorld [r][c] = ' ';
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I did this right but my edited nextGen method now looks like what is shown above. I also edited my changeCell method to match your edit by now my outputs look totally off. Any tips? Also sorry for my lack of understanding, I'm new to programming and Java in general.

Comment: This line specifically messes up my changeCell method  `else if ((current=='*') && (count >= 2) || (count <= 3))` while this line  `if ((current == ' ') && (count == 3))` seems to work fine. Although it does seem like my issue resides in needing totally seperate arrays for World and Temp world.

Comment: Oops!  It should be `&&` instead of `||` in the second condition (I tried a few thing before posting and copied the wrong one).  I edited my answer.  Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In `getNeighbours` method you are counting all neighbours including the cell itself, then substracting it:

```
return numNeighbors-1;
```

However, if the cell you are checking is empty, you will get invalid count. That is, if you try checking the cell in these coordinates:

```
* * *
* O *
* * *
```

You will get 7 instead of actual number 8 (it's empty in center).

Looking at method `checkAllNeighbors`, it seems you've tried to account for that using `//if(world[i][j] == '*')` but you have commented it out as it is wrong according to Game Of Life rules.

This means that `changeCell` method gets neighbour counts wrong for empty cells.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, any idea on how I can correct the code?

Comment: Also regarding my x and y for the _italic_ **bold** `getNeighbours` method, I'm sure I mislabeled it but I don't think that it would fix my issue by changing it.